# swift sodium Decrypt using Private Key

Tags: php, ios, swift, libsodium, sodium

I am using Swift Sodium on client side as my server is using libsodium to encrypt the data before sharing it with me through API.

Now I have a existing private key and a public key in a String format with me. I want to now decrypt the encrypted data at my end on iOS using Swift.

How do I generate a Sodium Key Pair using the public and private key that I have?

Also Ideally I should use only the private key to decrypt the data. So how do I do that using only private key as String.

My Code for decryption is shown below -

```
func decryptData(dataString: String) -> String? {
    let sodium = Sodium()
    let privateKey = sodium?.utils.hex2bin("MY_SECRET_KEY")

    let publicKey = sodium?.utils.hex2bin("MY_PUBLIC_KEY")

    let message = dataString.data(using: .utf8)!

    if let decrypted = sodium?.box.open(anonymousCipherText: message, recipientPublicKey: publicKey!, recipientSecretKey: privateKey!){
        // authenticator is valid, decrypted contains the original message
        return String(data: decrypted, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String!
    }
    return nil
}
```

In the above Code my decrypted String is always empty.

The server is encrypting the data using the below function -

```
protected function crypt($response)
{
   $message = new HiddenString($response);

   $repository = \App::make(EncryptionKeysRepository::class);
   $enc = $repository->findOneBy(['device' => 'android']);
   $dir = $enc->getDevice();
   $publicKey = $enc->getPublicKey();
   $storage = storage_path();

   if(!file_exists($storage."/{$dir}/")) {
       mkdir($storage."/{$dir}/");
   }

   // save key pair to key store
   $pubFilename = \tempnam($storage."/{$dir}/", 'pub_key');
   file_put_contents($pubFilename, $publicKey);

   $public = KeyFactory::loadEncryptionPublicKey($pubFilename);
   unlink($pubFilename);
   rmdir($storage."/{$dir}/");
   $message = Crypto::seal($message, $public);

   return $message;
}
```

Decrypting Logic at server

```
protected function deCrypt($response)
{
   $repository = \App::make(EncryptionKeysRepository::class);
   $enc = $repository->findOneBy(['device' => 'android']);
   $dir = $enc->getDevice();
   $publicKey = $enc->getSecretKey();
   $storage = storage_path();

   if(!file_exists($storage."/{$dir}/")) {
       mkdir($storage."/{$dir}/");
   }

   // save key pair to key store
   $secFilename = \tempnam($storage."/{$dir}/", 'sec_key');
   file_put_contents($secFilename, $publicKey);

   $secret = KeyFactory::loadEncryptionSecretKey($secFilename);
   unlink($secFilename);
   rmdir($storage."/{$dir}/");
   $res = Crypto::unseal($response, $secret);

   $message = $res->getString();

   return response()->json(compact('message'));
}
```

Comment: In what format do you have your `dataString`? Maybe it's base64 or some other format and you have to decode it before decryption?

Comment: @algrid Its just a String which is encrypted. No encoding on top of it so decoding is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

So, server-side, you're apparently using PHP, with a library called Halite.

I'm not very familiar with Halite, but looking at its code, `Crypto::seal()` uses sealed boxes, so `Box::open(anonymousCipherText: Data, recipientPublicKey: PublicKey, recipientSecretKey: SecretKey) -> Data?` is the correct method to decrypt this in Swift.

However, Halite also seems to encode the result as a BASE64 string (urlsafe variant).

So, you need to decode this first. Or, and this is going to be way more efficient, do not encode the ciphertext. Unless you have to read them aloud, the keys probably don't need to be encoded either.

Comment: I tried decoding it but the decoded data is always nil so I am assuming its not base64 encoded. I used this - `let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: dataString)`

Comment: Make sure you use the right BASE64 variant. As stated above, by default, Halite seems to use the URLsafe variant of BASE64.

Comment: Checked with all variants Frank. I dont think its base64encoded honestly as everything gives nil

Comment: Also added the decryption logic on the server side which is working fine and able to decrypt the same String

Comment: It's encoded, or else JSON encoding would probably fail as well. Check that the length of the ciphertext after decoding is equal to the length of the original message plus 48 bytes. How was the key pair generated on the device? Or are you using the same key pair everywhere? In that case, you'd better use symmetric encryption.

Comment: You may also want to add PHP and Halite to the title of your question.

Comment: Frank i am using the same key pair everywhere. They were generated at the server.

Comment: Key pairs must be unique to every device, or else anyone will be able to decrypt the data anyway. So, if you want to use the same secret key everywhere, use symmetric encryption. Still, check that the data you send before encoding matches the one you get after decoding. Even just with random data.